# How to put expression in ggplot title/label/legend from character vector?

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, legend

I want to generate legend labels with code and use them as expressions because they contain greek letters and subscripts. However the same problem occurs with the title, and it is much easier to show, so I will use that in my example.

```
ggplot() + ggtitle(expression(beta[a]^{4}))
```

[image]

This code works as expected, I got a nice title with β and subscript and superscript. However, if I have a string, I cannot convert it to an expression, or at least it doesn't display well on ggplot. Does anyone know how to use/convert character type vectors as expressions for ggplot?

```
title_expression <- "beta[a]^{4}"
ggplot() + ggtitle(as.expression(title_expression))
```

[image]

Code for my actual problem with legends:

```
legend_labels <- c("beta[d]^{2}", "beta[d]^{3}")
dat <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,2,3), b = c("a", "a", "b", "b"))

ggplot(dat, aes(a, fill = b)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), labels = legend_labels)
```

Comment: If you want to turn a character string into an expression, you need to parse it. `ggtitle(parse(text = title_expression))`.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed answers my question with the title! Is it possible to use this method for legend labels where I have a character vector?

Comment: Yes, of course: `scale_color_discrete(labels = lapply(c("a^1", "b^2", "c^3"), \(x) parse(text = x)))`

Comment: hmm, the backslash doesn't work for me instead of `function` but it works well if I replace it! Thanks a lot! Will you make it an official answer?

Comment: The short-hand syntax was introduced very recently. I suggest you update R if you can.

Comment: ohh good to know, that's a really cool change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be preferable to create an expression instead of a character string.

If you want to turn a character string into an expression, you need to parse it:

```
title_expression <- "beta[a]^{4}"
ggplot() + ggtitle(parse(text = title_expression))


dat <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,2,3), b = c("a", "a", "b", "b"))
legend_labels <- c("beta[d]^{2}", "beta[d]^{3}")

ggplot(dat, aes(a, fill = b)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), 
    labels = lapply(legend_labels, \(x) parse(text = x)))
```

Replace `\(x)` with `function(x)` if you use an outdated R version.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** You could use `parse(text = ..)`

```
ggplot(dat, aes(a, fill = b)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), labels = parse(text = legend_labels))
```

Here is a way with `expression`

```
legend_labels <- c(expression(beta[a]^4), expression(beta[a]^3))
dat <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,2,3), b = c("a", "a", "b", "b"))

ggplot(dat, aes(a, fill = b)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), labels = legend_labels)
```

[image]

Comment: That is cool and works for this mock example, but I want to generate the legend labels because I have different plots with 5-8 legend names and I want to avoid typing them one-by-one. Can you somehow generate expressions with code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please see may edit. Is that what you meant?